# Rendering mesh polygons in OpenGL - very slow

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, render

I recently switched from intermediate mode and have a new rendering process. There must be something I am not understanding. I think it has something to do with the indices.

Here is my diagram: Region->Mesh->Polygon Array->3 vertex indices which references the master list of vertices.

Here my render code:

```
// Render the mesh
void WLD::render(GLuint* textures, long curRegion, CFrustum cfrustum)
{

    int num = 0;

    // Set up rendering states
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set up my indices
    GLuint indices[3];

    // Cycle through the PVS
    while(num < regions[curRegion].visibility.size())
    {
        int i = regions[curRegion].visibility[num];

        // Make sure the region is not "dead"
        if(!regions[i].dead && regions[i].meshptr != NULL)
        {
            // Check to see if the mesh is in the frustum
            if(cfrustum.BoxInFrustum(regions[i].meshptr->min[0], regions[i].meshptr->min[2], regions[i].meshptr->min[1], regions[i].meshptr->max[0], regions[i].meshptr->max[2], regions[i].meshptr->max[1]))
            {
                // Cycle through every polygon in the mesh and render it
                for(int j = 0; j < regions[i].meshptr->polygonCount; j++)
                {   
                    // Assign the index for the polygon to the index in the huge vertex array
                    // This I think, is redundant
                    indices[0] = regions[i].meshptr->poly[j].vertIndex[0];
                    indices[1] = regions[i].meshptr->poly[j].vertIndex[1];
                    indices[2] = regions[i].meshptr->poly[j].vertIndex[2];

                    // Enable texturing and bind the appropriate texture
                    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[regions[i].meshptr->poly[j].tex]);

                    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].x);

                    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].u);

                    // Draw
                    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
                }
            }
        }
    num++;
    }

    // End of rendering - disable states
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Sorry if I left anything out. And I really appreciate feedback and help with this. I would even consider paying someone who is good with OpenGL and optimization to help me with this.

Comment: I've made it so it only binds textures when it calls for one that is not currently bound. That increased the FPS by about 10-15.

Comment: Arrange your mesh data so that you can draw all polygons of the same texture in one glDrawElements-call. So instead of looping every polygon you would loop something like meshptr->textureCount where you have stored the indices and texture-id for that texture. And you only need to enable gl_texture_2d once outside the loop or in your initialization. Also if you have control of the mesh-content try to use a single texture for the whole mesh (or several meshes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no point in using array rendering if you're only rendering 3 vertices at a time. The idea is to send *thousands* through with a single call. That is, you render a single "Polygon Array" or "Mesh" with one call.

Comment: Okay. So, I want to render every vertex in a mesh (hundreds of polygons). So how should I modify my code? Which rendering method should I be using? I can get the starting index in the vertex array and then the last polygon index for that mesh and render the range.

Comment: What if for each mesh, I was to keep a integer of the first vertex and last vertex in the rendering process. Then, I could draw just that specific mesh, granted that it is in the frustum, with glDrawRangeElements. The only thing I am confused about is what I would use for indices. I have my huge vertex array, my start vertex end vertex for the mesh and not sure where the indices fit in. Thank you.

Comment: One way is to change your datastructure to accomodate for storing polygons-per-material  the first place, in so called 'submeshes'. You then simply put all polygons for a single submesh in a glDrawElements call. As a side note, given the current state of your code, are you _really_ sure your manual frustum culling is a good thing?

Comment: @Satchmo In this case you have to keep integers for the first and last index of a mesh (not the vertices), as the indices are the ones that say what is drawn. The `first` and `last` parameters of `glDrawRangeElements` are just hints and don't limit what is actually drawn.